# I have a problem with uploading a file, with this error: Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected

Tags: java, excel, parsing

```
public List<Map<String, String>> parseExcelFileWithHeaders(
        MultipartFile file,
        List<String> headersList) 
{
    List<Map<String, String>> parsedFile = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = 
             new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
        List<String> headers = headersList;
        Map<String, String> cells = new HashMap<>();

        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int colNum = 0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                cells.put(headers.get(colNum++), 
                          getCharValue(cell).toString());
            }
            parsedFile.add(cells);

        }

        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return parsedFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that you didn't initialize the POI logging subsystem correctly, and as a result, the logging that would be done by one of these methods can't write the (probable) error or output to the Logger.

I would look outside of this block of code to see if you can correctly configure the logging, and then see what the log output has to say about the issue that this block of code is raising.